# Grep across the file system has no output in a shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I'm trying to create a pre-commit hook in Git that will check for any debugging code and prompt the user to fix it. I have a regex that I'm grepping for (ignore the fact that it won't exclude occurrences in multiline comments!):

```
grep -IiRn --exclude-dir={node_modules,vendor,public,lib,contrib} --include=\*.{module,inc,install,php,js} -P '^\s*(?!\/\/)\s*(dpm\(|dsm\(|console.log\()' /path/to/code/
```

This works fine when I run it normally in the console, but when I try it in an executable `.sh` script it does nothing. None of the following has worked for me:

```
#!/bin/sh

grep ...

MYVAR =`grep ...` # Note the backticks!
echo $MYVAR

MYVAR =$(grep ...)
echo $MYVAR

MYVAR ="`grep ...`"
echo $MYVAR
```

I tried doing it with Python and `os.system()` but that did nothing either. It seems to just have no STDOUT. There's possibly something obvious I'm missing but I'm at a loose end.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

## Edit:

This is the exact script, even though it's at the earliest possible stage due to not being able to actually do the first bit. I've hidden the exact folder names because it's probably best to not share my company's code base on SO ;)

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Test!"

ONE=`grep -IiRn --exclude-dir={node_modules,vendor,public,lib,contrib} --include=\*.{module,inc,install,php,js} -P '^\s*(?!\/\/)\s*(dpm\(|dsm\(|console.log\()' /company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/`

TWO=$(grep -IiRn --exclude-dir={node_modules,vendor,public,lib,contrib} --include=\*.{coffee} -P '^\s*(?!\#)\s*(dpm\(|dsm\(|console.log)' /company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/)

echo $ONE
echo "$TWO"
```

... and running `bash -x pre-commit` returns:

```
ubuntu@ip-12-34-56-78:/company/projects/company/scripts$ bash -x pre-commit
+ echo 'Test!'
Test!
++ grep -IiRn --exclude-dir=node_modules --exclude-dir=vendor --exclude-dir=public --exclude-dir=lib --exclude-dir=contrib '--include=*.module' '--include=*.inc' '--include=*.install' '--include=*.php' '--include=*.js' -P '^\s*(?!\/\/)\s*(dpm\(|dsm\(|console.log\()' /company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/
+ ONE='/company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/some_module/some_module.report.inc:594:  dsm('\''test'\'');
/company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/goals_app/goals_app.module:170:  console.log(e.stack);
/company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/company_usage_reports/js/script.js:300:          console.log('\''fetch success'\'');
/company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/another_module/js/another_module_change_workgroup.js:19:    console.log('\''wtf?'\'');
/company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/another_module/js/another_module_reorder_table.js:33:                  console.log(resp);
/company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/another_module/js/another_module_reorder_table.js:39:              console.log(ui.placeholder);
/company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/another_module/js/another_module_goal_form.js:4:      console.log($( ".required" ));
/company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/another_module/js/another_module_reorder.js:40:                  console.log(resp);
/company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/company_goals/js/views/goal-list.js:87:          console.log(data);'
++ grep -IiRn --exclude-dir=node_modules --exclude-dir=vendor --exclude-dir=public --exclude-dir=lib --exclude-dir=contrib '--include=*.{coffee}' -P '^\s*(?!\#)\s*(dpm\(|dsm\(|console.log)' /company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/
+ TWO=
+ echo /company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/some_module/some_module.report.inc:594: 'dsm('\''test'\'');' /company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/goals_app/goals_app.module:170: 'console.log(e.stack);' /company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/company_usage_reports/js/script.js:300: 'console.log('\''fetch' 'success'\'');' /company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/another_module/js/another_module_change_workgroup.js:19: 'console.log('\''wtf?'\'');' /company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/another_module/js/another_module_reorder_table.js:33: 'console.log(resp);' /company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/another_module/js/another_module_reorder_table.js:39: 'console.log(ui.placeholder);' /company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/another_module/js/another_module_goal_form.js:4: 'console.log($(' '".required"' '));' /company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/another_module/js/another_module_reorder.js:40: 'console.log(resp);' /company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/company_goals/js/views/goal-list.js:87: 'console.log(data);'
/company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/some_module/some_module.report.inc:594: dsm('test'); /company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/goals_app/goals_app.module:170: console.log(e.stack); /company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/company_usage_reports/js/script.js:300: console.log('fetch success'); /company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/another_module/js/another_module_change_workgroup.js:19: console.log('wtf?'); /company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/another_module/js/another_module_reorder_table.js:33: console.log(resp); /company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/another_module/js/another_module_reorder_table.js:39: console.log(ui.placeholder); /company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/another_module/js/another_module_goal_form.js:4: console.log($( ".required" )); /company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/another_module/js/another_module_reorder.js:40: console.log(resp); /company/projects/company/www/sites/all/modules/custom/company_goals/js/views/goal-list.js:87: console.log(data);
+ echo ''
```

... but running it without the `-x` flag STILL doesn't work.

## Edit two:

In case anyone is wondering, my env is as follows...

```
ubuntu@ip-12-34-56-78:~$ uname -a
Linux ip-12-34-56-78 3.2.0-31-virtual #50-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 7 16:36:36 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ubuntu@ip-12-34-56-78:~$ whereis sh && whereis bash
sh: /bin/sh /bin/sh.distrib /usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz
bash: /bin/bash /etc/bash.bashrc /usr/share/man/man1/bash.1.gz
```

Comment: You can't have spaces before or after the equal sign `=` in the variable assignment. Try `MYVAR=$( .... )` with no spaces. Also it would be better to quote the variable in the `echo` command, as in `echo "$MYVAR"`, otherwise possible newlines will be converted to spaces

Comment: Thanks for the response- neither of those things made a difference though.

Comment: post your actual script

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question just to get it out of the way, but I assume you're script is in the same folder and you're running it from the same folder as when you ran the `grep` manually (just to make sure apples to apples comparison)?

Comment: The folder I'm searching in starts at the root of the filesystem anyway, so I can't imagine it should make any difference, should it?

Comment: If the path you are `grep`ing is absolute (starts with `/`) then, no, it shouldn't.

Comment: may be you have a script with the same name in the path that does something else , try executing the script with full path

Comment: So you're saying when you run `bash /company/projects/company/scripts/pre-commit` without `-x` you get **no** output?

Comment: Sorry, no- I still get "Test!". I've just tried it and it miraculously worked. I don't know whether I was doing various incorrect combinations of things up until this exact point, but it seems to now work with `bash pre-commit` but not `sh pre-commit`. It also only appears to work with `$()` rather than backticks. Peculiar!

Comment: I updated my answer to include this, but you should know that `/bin/sh` on Ubuntu points to dash, a much more restrictive shell than bash.

Comment: Thanks again, I had literally no idea about that. Useful info for the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say for sure until you post the actual script you're running, but in your current code snippet have

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Depending on your OS, this may be a link to `/bin/bash`, for example, or it may be the actual Bourne shell, which [does not support brace expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29#Brace_expansion) (e.g. `{a, b, c}`). Even if `/bin/sh` does point to `/bin/bash` on your machine, you should only use portable constructs if your shebang is `#!/bin/sh` (i.e. say what you mean). If you want to use brace expansion in your script, change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash`.

If you put

```
set -x
```

at the top of your script, it will print detailed information that can help with debugging. You can also do this by invoking the shell directly instead of modifying your script, for example

```
sh -x /path/to/script
```

or

```
bash -x /path/to/script
```

---

**EDIT:** On Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is dash, the Debian Almquist shell. Like the Bourne shell, dash is fairly restrictive, and does not support brace expansion. See [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) for a discussion of portability issues and dash.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Well, there isn't actually anything more to add. The snippet *is* the code, pretty much. I tried with `#!/bin/bash` instead and it made no difference. Give me a second and I'll edit my question...

Comment: @MattFletcher Actually, there is more to add: you replaced much of your script with ellipses. It is very difficult to debug something that you can't see, which might explain why there aren't more answers to your question. In general on SO, you should post complete code (copy-paste the script you *actually ran*), as well as input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: I did that only because I thought having the same very long line of code that runs off the edge repeated several times would make it harder to read and distract people from the point in question. I've updated my question now, should hopefully be a bit more verbose :) Cheers

Comment: +1: As mentioned in a comment to my question, it was indeed that `bash` was required not `sh`, if anyone in the future is reading this. Thanks for the help!